# slide down the navbar after srcoll up the window

Tags: javascript

I couldn't manage slide down (Show) the navigation after scroll up with exact radio for example i want to slide down the navigation after scroll up 100px

```
if (enableChaser == 1 && tjq('#content').length > 0 && tjq('#main-menu ul.menu').length > 0) {
            var forchBottom;
            var chaser = tjq('#main-menu ul.menu').clone().hide().appendTo(document.body).wrap("<div class='chaser hidden-mobile'><div class='container'></div></div>");
            tjq('<h1 class="logo navbar-brand"><a title="Travelo - home" href="index.html"><img alt="" src="images/logo.png"></a></h1>').insertBefore('.chaser .menu');
            var forch = tjq('#content').first();
            forchBottom = forch.offset().top + 1;
            tjq(window).on('scroll', function () {
                var top = tjq(document).scrollTop();
                if (tjq(".chaser").is(":hidden") && top > forchBottom) {
                    tjq(".chaser").slideDown(300);
                    //chaser.fadeIn(300, shown);
                } else if (tjq(".chaser").is(":visible") && top < forchBottom) {
                    tjq(".chaser").slideUp(200);
                    //chaser.fadeOut(200, hidden);
                }
            });
            tjq(window).on('resize', function () {
                var top = tjq(document).scrollTop();
                if (tjq(".chaser").is(":hidden") && top > forchBottom) {
                    tjq(".chaser").slideDown(200);
                } else if (tjq(".chaser").is(":visible") && top < forchBottom) {
                    tjq(".chaser").slideUp(200);
                }
            });

            tjq(".chaser").css("visibility", "hidden");
            chaser.show();
            fixPositionMegaMenu(".chaser");
            tjq(".chaser .megamenu-menu").removeClass("light");
            //chaser.hide();
            tjq(".chaser").hide();
            tjq(".chaser").css("visibility", "visible");
        }
```

Comment: Can you share working fiddle what is exact issue you are facing?

Comment: you can find it live on the website: evisax.com the navbar slidedown when reach the last of the slider, but i want it to slidedown before reaching the last of the slider.

Comment: I don't see any issue in that. Can you explain in detail? What you want to slidedown and when(on scroll?)?

Comment: I want the navigation bar to be slider down before reach the end of the slider. In the website you can find the navigation bar slowdown exactly when you the scroll reach the end of the slider.

Comment: Did you get want i mean?

Comment: Did you mean, top navigation bar slide down when your banner slider reach last slide? even if window scroll position is 0 ie on top?

Comment: Ill try to explain it in a different way, i want the navigate bar to be sticky to the top once scroll, there is a blue bar before the navigation, i dont want it to be appeared after the scroll and i want to replace it with the navigation bar on the top.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150570/discussion-between-sam-mohamed-and-yogen-darji).